# Is it possible to call tensorboard smooth function manually?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have two arrays X and Y.

Is there a function I can call in tensorboard to do the smooth?

Right now I can do an alternative way in python like:

    `sav_smoooth = savgol_filter(Y, 51, 3)
    plt.plot(X, Y)`

But I am not sure what's way tensorboard do smooth. Is there a function I can call?

Thanks.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496989/download-smoothed-tensorboard-values/69353117#69353117

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the mathematics behind the "smoothing" parameter in TensorBoard's scalar graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281844/what-is-the-mathematics-behind-the-smoothing-parameter-in-tensorboards-scalar)

Answer (score 2):

So far I haven't found a way to call it manually, but you can construct a similar function,

based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281844/what-is-the-mathematics-behind-the-smoothing-parameter-in-tensorboards-scalar), the function will be something like

```
def smooth(scalars, weight):  # Weight between 0 and 1
    last = scalars[0]  # First value in the plot (first timestep)
    smoothed = list()
    for point in scalars:
        smoothed_val = last * weight + (1 - weight) * point  # Calculate smoothed value
        smoothed.append(smoothed_val)                        # Save it
        last = smoothed_val                                  # Anchor the last smoothed value

    return smoothed
```