# What is the mathematics behind the "smoothing" parameter in TensorBoard's scalar graphs?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I presume it is some kind of moving average, but the valid range is between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

It is called [exponential moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average), below is a code explanation how it is created.

Assuming all the **real** scalar values are in a list called `scalars` the smoothing is applied as follows:

```py
def smooth(scalars: List[float], weight: float) -> List[float]:  # Weight between 0 and 1
    last = scalars[0]  # First value in the plot (first timestep)
    smoothed = list()
    for point in scalars:
        smoothed_val = last * weight + (1 - weight) * point  # Calculate smoothed value
        smoothed.append(smoothed_val)                        # Save it
        last = smoothed_val                                  # Anchor the last smoothed value
        
    return smoothed
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

As @SaPropper [correctly pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75421930/5368083) out, TensorBoard now includes the debiasing factor.

Comment: I wish you could pick between that and a sliding moving average!

Comment: This was really helpful! Thanks.

Comment: This is not the Python equivalent to the TensorBoard implementation

Comment: To be more explicit: the TensorBoard implementation currently also has a debiasing factor, as in SaPropper's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the actual piece of source code that performs that exponential smoothing with some additional de-biasing explained in the comments to compensate for the choice of the zero initial value:

```
last = last * smoothingWeight + (1 - smoothingWeight) * nextVal
```

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/34877f15153e1a2087316b9952c931807a122aa7/tensorboard/components/vz_line_chart2/line-chart.ts#L714

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of EMA smoothing used for TensorBoard can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/34877f15153e1a2087316b9952c931807a122aa7/tensorboard/components/vz_line_chart2/line-chart.ts#L699).

The equivalent in Python is actually:

```
def smooth(scalars: list[float], weight: float) -> list[float]:
    """
    EMA implementation according to
    https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/34877f15153e1a2087316b9952c931807a122aa7/tensorboard/components/vz_line_chart2/line-chart.ts#L699
    """
    last = 0
    smoothed = []
    num_acc = 0
    for next_val in scalars:
        last = last * weight + (1 - weight) * next_val
        num_acc += 1
        # de-bias
        debias_weight = 1
        if weight != 1:
            debias_weight = 1 - math.pow(weight, num_acc)
        smoothed_val = last / debias_weight
        smoothed.append(smoothed_val)

    return smoothed
```

Answer (score -1):

a scipy solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42724386/10805680:

```py
from scipy.signal import lfilter

def smooth(scalars: np.ndarray, weight: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return lfilter([1. - weight], [1., -weight], scalars, zi=[arr[0]])[0]
```

much faster and numerically stable