# Download smoothed tensorboard values

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is it possible to downloaded the smooth values generated from Tensorboard or at least get the smoothing function to be able to generate the same graphics as in Tensorboard.

Comment: did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011419/is-it-possible-to-call-tensorboard-smooth-function-manually

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the mathematics behind the "smoothing" parameter in TensorBoard's scalar graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281844/what-is-the-mathematics-behind-the-smoothing-parameter-in-tensorboards-scalar)

Answer (score 1):

It has changed a bit recently, but currently TensorBoard [does exponential averaging for its smoothing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/a3166838a43baa50045e011da96517539fcc52a1/tensorboard/plugins/scalar/vz_line_chart/vz-line-chart.ts#L704). Should be quite easy to re-implement.

Comment: Thank you. if you know an implementation  let me know

Answer (score 0):

rate = 0.1 # range of 0.0 for no smoothing, 1.0 for overly perfect smoothing.

def ema(old:float, new:float, rate:float)->float:
  return old * rate + new * (1.0 - rate)

ema(10, 9, 0.1)

Answer (score 0):

they use some type of exp weighted avg. Try:

```
def my_tb_smooth(scalars: list[float], weight: float) -> list[float]:  # Weight between 0 and 1
    """

    ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011419/is-it-possible-to-call-tensorboard-smooth-function-manually

    :param scalars:
    :param weight:
    :return:
    """
    last = scalars[0]  # First value in the plot (first timestep)
    smoothed: list = []
    for point in scalars:
        smoothed_val = last * weight + (1 - weight) * point  # Calculate smoothed value
        smoothed.append(smoothed_val)                        # Save it
        last = smoothed_val                                  # Anchor the last smoothed value
    return smoothed
```

credit: [Is it possible to call tensorboard smooth function manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011419/is-it-possible-to-call-tensorboard-smooth-function-manually)